# Diffing between streams in Perforce

Tags: file, version-control, perforce

I'd like to be able to diff the same file or directory between two different perforce streams.  I know how to run a simple diff command against two files, but I'm trying to find a way to say via script that I want to diff file X with these streams (potentially having the stream names hard coded in a script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:  The below works for command line, but if you have P4V you can simply right click on the stream and say "Diff against parent" in the Streams view.  Awesome!

---

It looks like this is supported by p4 diff2, it just seems to be not working in my environment.  Specifically, it looks like you need to denote the depot name like so:

```
p4 diff2 -S //depot/streamname
```

-S stream [-P parent]
Diff a stream with its parent. To diff the stream with a stream other than its configured parent, specify -P.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/diff2.html

Comment: Note that 'p4 diff' and 'p4 diff2' are two different commands. One computes the difference between a file on your local machine versus a file in the server's repository; the other computes the difference between two files in the server's repository.